# Finish geolocation in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I end the real-time geolocation service when I close the activity and move on to another one, for example MapReceiver to AppHome, since when I do so the GPS is still active and continues to update my database in Firebase realtime until I close the app completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dispose method when you leave the page or if you want to close the service. Note that dispose method is only supported inside Stateful widget only.

```
@override
void dispose(){
  super.dispose();

  // write code to close your streams,services, etc. here

}
```